# gf: can I get next file that matches?

Tags: filesystem

I use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to open "filename.h" from line like:

```
#include "filename.h"
```

in some C\C++ file.

Sometimes there is more than one "filename.h" that <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> command can find in *path*. But <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> gets me to the first file it finds - sometimes that's not what I want.

Is there a way to open the next file matching that name?

Comment: `gf` accepts a count, so you can try `2gf`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Didn't expect that - but it works. Any idea if it's possible to cycle through the results?

Comment: @muru please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct response. Don't think there is anything better out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`:h gf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#gf):

```
                                                       gf E446 E447
[count]gf               Edit the file whose name is under or after the cursor.
 ...
                        If a [count] is given, the count'th file that is found
                        in the 'path' is edited.
```

So you can do `2gf`.

To browse the list of matches is trickier. The only way I found was to use use `:find` and Vim's command-line tab completion:

```
:find <cfile>Tab
```

Vim will cycle through matches and `<cfile>`:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `<cfile>`? _`<cfile>`    is replaced with the path name under the cursor (like what `gf` uses)_

Comment: @Shahbaz indeed, corrected.